# Warnings using glmer() in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, biostatistics

I'm trying to analyze the differences in the number of plant species found in different types of fields. The number of species per sample is a non-integer because I had to adjust the number to account for how many plants I counted per sample. 
This is the code:

```r
m2b<-glmer.nb(two.percent~Management2+(1|Site/Farmer),data=pollen_diversity,
             control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=100000000)))
```

Whenever I used the non-integer proportion values, I would get 50 warnings about "non-integer values" when running the code for the different models. The warnings looked like this:

```r
11: In (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, ... :
non-integer x = 1.300000
12: In pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GHrule(0L), ... :
non-integer x = 1.400000
```

So, I rounded the values in excel and ran the code again. I still get 14 warning messages. Here are the first two:

```r
1: In theta.ml(Y, mu, weights = object@resp $ weights, limit = limit, ... :
iteration limit reached

2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt $ par, ctrl = control $$ checkConv, ... :
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00261426 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

The other twelve warnings look a lot like the second one. It's "`opt$par`".

I realized that I find several significant differences between field types when I run the data for the six-grain level with unrounded values, but if I run the data with rounded values, I find no significant differences. So clearly something is wrong. What might be causing this?

```r
Some info on the data:  
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.950   7.545   9.030   9.728  11.880  15.000
```

Comment: The [Nelder-Mead optimizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) is more robust, so sometimes just switching to it helps the software find a solution.

Comment: @whuber Would you offer me some guidance on how to do that?  I'm a student and only know how to do a few things in R

Comment: Type `?glmerControl` and read the instructions.

Comment: Okay thank you. I switched the optimizer, but it didn't work. I still get the same warning

Comment: For your last run, since the criterion is pretty close to the threshold, it may be beneficial to run the algorithm for a few more iterations. But you shouldn't force your outcome variable to integer but rather include the number of samples you took as an offset.

Comment: @vkehayas Thank you, how do I change the iteration number? Where do I put that in the code? And how do I include sample number as an offset?

Comment: To increase the number of iterations: `control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e9))` (which comes from glmerControl that @whuber suggested to you to read). To include an offset, add `offset(log(nSample))` in your formula.